# Что такое разделитель ::?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

К примеру, `return ::operator new(bytes);`. Это же не оператор области видимости? В примере было написано, что это разделитель. Возможно, я не так понял и так просто называется какой-то трюк с этим оператором области видимости. Не знаю нужно ли приводить код, но вот:

```
#define kPoolSize 4096

struct Pool {
    unsigned char* next;
    unsigned char space[kPoolSize];
    Pool() : next(&space[0]) {}
};

class Foo {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t bytes)
    {
        return ::operator new(bytes);
    }

    void* operator new(size_t bytes, Pool* pool)
    {
        void* space = pool->next;
        pool->next += bytes;
        return space;
    }
};

int main(){
    Pool localPool;
    Foo* foo1 = new Foo;
    Foo* foo2 = new(&localPool) Foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я Вам советую почитать книжку С++ Бьерна Страуструп. Оч. хорошо все описано.

Comment: @Zver25, какую из них и какого года? Или лучше, если прочитать все его книги?

Comment: фу ты, я уже подумал, какой-то новый оператор `::?` появился )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Интернеты говорят нам, что это оператор разрешения контекста:

Оператор разрешения контекста — является оператором с самым высоким приоритетом в языке. Он применяется в двух формах:

::i //одноместный оператор – ссылается на внешний контекст

foo bar::i //двухместный оператор – ссылается на контекст класса

Одноместная форма используется для раскрытия или обращения к имени, относящемуся ко внешнему контексту и скрытому локальным контекстом или контекстом класса.

---

К примеру есть класс **myClass** с функцией **myFunc**.

```
class myClass
{
   public:
     myClass(){};
     ~myClass();
     int myFunc(void){return 1;};
};
```

Чтобы вызвать в коде функцию **myFunc**, используется оператор разрешения контекста:

```
int main(void)  
{
   int a = myClass::myFunc();  
   return 0;  
}
```

---

Тоже самое происходит с вызовом функций из различных *namespace*.

Comment: **static** int myFunc(void){return 1**;**};

Comment: зачем тут статик?

Comment: обращение вида myClass::myFunc() это вызов функций класса (статических методов), они помечаются как static.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, то есть одноместный оператор нужен только для доступа к внешним объектам, чтобы разрешать спорные ситуации как у меня в коде например, когда возврат без одноместного оператора дал бы рекурсию?

Comment: @mzarb: или когда вы пишете шаблон, и не знаете, в каком точно контексте будет он инстанциирован.

Comment: @mzarb, у вас есть глобальная переменная myInt. Вы пишите функцию, в которой тоже есть локальная переменная myInt. К локальной переменной myInt вы обращаетесь так __a = myInt;__, а к глобальной (внешней) __a = ::myInt;__.